# Access Denied or Certificate not found when running application on IIS server

Tags: c#, ssl, client-certificates

**Situation**

Greetings

I am working on an application that requires me to make use of a certificate. I must stress everything works 100% from my local machine and I only experience issues when I try to run it on my server using IIS.

This is my certificate code.

```
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        debugging += "\\n  about to add certificate";
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        var certificate = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "test-online.com", true)[0];
        debugging += "\\n  certificate attached successfully.";
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
```

**What Have I Done**

So I have installed the certificate (I did this for both CurrentUser and LocalMachine store) attempted to place it in personal stored, trusted and trusted publisher but once I use `CurrentUser` as store location I am getting the error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.get_Item(Int32 index) at` almost like it can't find the certificate in the certificate store.

I have also attempted to use LocalMachine store. In doing this, I read that I could give access to the primary key to the user that is running my application (Network Service in my case)  . However doing that I only get `Access is denied. at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags flags)`.

I would appreciate if I could get some help with this as I do not know what else I could try. I have reinstalled the certificate, installed it as being able to be exported, tried different identity ( in the application pool), read similar questions, yet I am unable to solve this. I do not know if I have to somehow give IIS some sort of access to the certificate because like I said it works fine if I run from my laptop but running on the server is a no go.

Comment: I suggest you do some work to isolate the problem. Try retrieving some other certificate. Or enumerate over the `Certificates` collection and dump all of them to a log file to see if the certificate is there but maybe misspelled. Check to make sure that your application is running under the same identify as you. Or install the certificate in the machine store instead.

Comment: @JohnWu when I try to use local machine store I get  "Access denied" Can you suggest where I can find / handle that access?